# Why are 3 files are downloaded?(@font-face)

Tags: css, create-react-app, font-face, styled-components

I am using font-face and I am using CRA and styled components.

Why my 3 files are downloaded?

In my GlobalStyles.js files,

```
/* open-sans-regular - latin */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
        url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
        url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
        url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
        url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
        url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.svg#OpenSans') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  }
```

I am checking in both Chrome and Firefox and versions are latest. Shouldn't browser download only woff2 file? Why does it also download woff and ttf?

```
url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
```

Downloaded files are

url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */

url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */

url('../fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */

Comment: Are you asking for the download location? Your question "Why your 3 files are downloaded?" Is clearly because that's what you expect it to do, to download. Consider checking the grammar and editing your question because there is ambiguity in it

Comment: I expected it to download only 1 font as well, so either my expectations are wrong, or the browsers are trying desperately to download a font that contains the characters you want printed. For example, if you want to display a ლ, but the woff2 file doesn't contain the ლ, the browser might try the woff and ttf files. Not sure though; must check.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/13609119/1016716

Comment: I am trying to ask why "woff2" file is not enough for Chrome? why does it download second one (woff) and third one(ttf)? I consider latest versions of Chrome and firefox as modern browser.

By the way, project is on the early stage, I just added some small text and one button, which probably doesn't need special character.